# d3 "Ghost trail" on bars when transitioning axis and element simultaneously

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar chart with an x axis that is updated on a change in a drop down menu. Both the x axis and the bars usually have to change, depending on the data. The update works correctly without a transition. When I add in the transition, "ghost lines" of the original bars will be left behind while the bars move. They will be left there until the transition is finished, then disappear. This only occurs when the axis must change--if the axis is the same between the two updates, there is no ghosting effect.

The effect can be seen here: 
[mbostock’s block #4061961 Bullet Charts](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961)

If you click update a few times, eventually you will see the ghosting effect on the slim black line as it moves to the right.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this behavior?

**UPDATE:**
Screenshot mid-transition of the chart I created: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqFf5.jpg

I am using Firefox 32.0.3.

Comment: I am unable to see it on the example you provided. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not seeing this effect. Perhaps someone else can weigh in. I'm on the latest FF release.